# regex to make the string meaningful. python

Tags: python, regex

how to remove non-english words (vocabulary) from the string

for example:

```
puppies monitoring_string = c1299fe10ba49eb54f197dd4f735fcdc dogtime
```

How to remove all non-english word, keep the vocabulary:
the result I would like to get is :

```
puppies monitoring string dogtime
```

or

```
puppies monitoring string  ....or others
```

the purpose is to make the string meaningful.

what I tried was:

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', string)
result:   puppies monitoring string c1299fe10ba49eb54f197dd4f735fcdc dogtime
```

Comment: Please define 'non-english word'.

Comment: non proper vocabulary

Comment: Regex is not the correct tool. You need a list of words, then split the string by spaces and see which entries are in the word list. Although this a simplistic approach with many flaws.

Comment: Plus, you need rules to dermined derived forms of words.

Comment: how do you think `"1-2-3 mill"` is a proper vocabulary word? Also, how aout `"2,4-D"`(a synthetic auxin widely used as a weedkiller) ?

Comment: `dogtime`?  That's not an English word is it?   If you are on UNIX/Linux then the `words` file might help, it is usually in /usr/share/dict/words or /usr/dict/words.  You could load the words into a `set` (it would be large) and just use the `in` keyword for validation.  There are limitations to the `words` file of course, but its a good place to start.

Comment: You may try NLTK to deal with this, but if a true word is missing in the corpus, you will get a word removed. If a word has a typo in it, it will also be removed.

Comment: You may also try loading the dictionary into a trie. Google has a decent open source one.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any logic words possess that non-words do not.

To start, maybe you can try removing words with numbers in them.

The regex `\w*\d\w*` should find letter combos with numbers and numbers.